# vpn.domain.com became suddenly unaccessible

Tags: networking, vpn, domain

I work 3 days in the office (Belgium) and 2 days remote from home (Spain). I use the company's VPN to connect to their network when working from home. First step is to go to their webpage vpn.companyname.be and log in with my credentials. The the software kicks in and a connection is established. This has worked for me without a glitch for the best part of a year.

Until recently. All of a sudden I was unable to access vpn.companyname.be. I thought the site was down but the helpdesk could still enter. Not just from within the company network but also using a mobile connection. My sister (in another country) was also presented the login page.

My brother in law though, (in Spain like me and having the same provider) could NOT enter.

Helpdesk told me that it looked like my provider was to blame and I have to say that sounds plausible. They also said that "this happens sometimes" and that the problem might be fixed the next day. And it was! The next day I had access to vpn.companyname.be as if nothing had ever happened.

But the funny thing is that I was always able to reach www.companyname.be, also during the time I could not access vpn.companyname.be.
So that proves the domain companyname.be could be resolved to its IP address.

Does anybody have a logical explanation for all this? How is it possible that "www" is let through and "vpn" is not.
If this would happen again, is there anything I can do (apart from calling my provider). Like changing DNS server settings or something like that.

Comment: "So that proves the domain companyname.be could be resolved to its IP address."  No it doesn't, as VPN. and WWW. may not (probably don't) point to the same server.  AS-is there's not enough information here for us to do anything but guess.  You need to do some diagnostics, like pinging the host (by name and then by IP to determine if it's a name resolution failure), and then tracing a route to the host to find where the failure is happening (if it's along the route between you and the server).

Comment: Use the IP address instead.